# Replacing text in XWPFParagraph without changing format of the docx file

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I am developing font converter app which will convert *Unicode* font text to *Krutidev/Shree Lipi* (Marathi/Hindi) font text. In the original docx file there are formatted words (i.e. Color, Font, size of the text, Hyperlinks..etc. ).
I want to keep format of the final docx same as the original docx after converting words from Unicode to another font.

PFA.

[image: Input docx]

[image: Current Output]

Here is my Code

```java
try {
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("StartDoc.docx");
    document = new XWPFDocument(fileInputStream);
    XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);
    List<XWPFParagraph> paragraph = document.getParagraphs();
    Converter data = new Converter() ;
    for(XWPFParagraph p :document.getParagraphs())
    {           
        for(XWPFRun r :p.getRuns())
        {           
            String string2 = r.getText(0);
            data.uniToShree(string2);
            r.setText(string2,0);
        }
    }
    //Write the Document in file system

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Output.docx");
    document.write(out);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("Output.docx written successully");

} 
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("We had an error while reading the Word Doc");
}
```

Comment: Process it run-by-run within the paragraph?

Comment: @Gagravarr please guide me if i am doing something wrong in the above code.

Comment: You need to work run-by-run not paragraph-by-paragraph if you want to keep the formatting. Get your paragraphs as now, but then get the runs within those

Comment: @Gagravarr i tried this code but error occurs. Null pointer exception at Converter.uniToKrutidev. for(XWPFParagraph p :document.getParagraphs()){
                for(XWPFRun r :p.getRuns()){
                    String string2 = r.getText(0);
                    String dataa;
                    dataa = Converter.uniToKrutidev(string2);
                    r.setText(dataa,0);
                }
            }

Comment: @Gagravarr Please can you tell me where is the mistake in the above code.

Comment: You need to edit your code into your question, then indicate which line the problem is happening with. Random multi-line code in comments isn't much use to anyone...

Comment: @Gagravarr Ok. Now see the edited code. Error occurs - Null pointer exception at Converter.uniToKrutidev(string 2).

Comment: And where's the code for that? Where does that object get created?

Comment: Sorry that line was missing. Actullay I copied the old code from my smartphone. Added In try block.

Comment: @Gagravarr upto two pages only text is getting translated into the required format. How to parse 3 or more pages.? Or is there any way to maintain the style of docx without using XWPFrun ?

Comment: Runs hold formatting. You need to stick to replacing the text in runs if you want to maintain formats. As for pages, there must be another bug in your code, Word is a run-based not page-based format, so there's no page changes in the file format!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for ask-an-answer.
I have worked using POI some years ago, but over excel-workbooks, but still I’ll try to help you reach the root cause of your error.

The Java compiler is smart enough to suggest good debugging information in itself!
A good first step to disambiguate the error is to not overwrite the exception message provided to you via the compiler complain.

Try printing the results of e.getLocalizedMessage()or e.getMessage() and see what you get.
Getting the stack trace using printStackTrace  method is also useful oftentimes to pinpoint where your error lies!

Share your findings from the above method calls to further help you help debug the issue.

**[EDIT 1:]**

So it seems, you are able to process the file just right with respect to the font conversion of the data, but you are not able to reconstruct the formatting of the original data in the converted data file.
(thus, "We had an error while reading the Word Doc", is a lie getting printed ;) )

Now, there are 2 elements to a Word document:

1. Content
2. Structure or Schema

You are able to convert the data as you are working only on the content of your respective doc files.
In order to be able to retain the formatting of the contents, your solution needs to be aware of the formatting of the doc files as well and take care of that.

MS Word which defined the doc files and their extension (.docx) follows a particular set of schemas that define the rules of formatting. These schemas are defined in Microsoft's XML Namespace packages[1].

You can obtain the XML(HTML) format of the doc-file you want quite easily (see steps in [1] or code in link [2]) and even apply different schemas or possibly your own schema definitions based on the definitions provided by MS's namespaces, either programmatically, for which you need to get versed with XML, XSL and XSLT concepts (w3schools[3] is a good starting point) but this method is no less complex than writing your own version of MS-Word; or using MS-Word's inbuilt tools as shown in [1].

[1]. [https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2231769&seqNum=4#:~:text=During%20conversion%2C%20Word%20tags%20the,you%20can%20an%20HTML%20file](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2231769&seqNum=4#:%7E:text=During%20conversion%2C%20Word%20tags%20the,you%20can%20an%20HTML%20file).

[2]. https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/testcases/org/apache/poi/hwpf/converter/TestWordToHtmlConverter.java

[3]. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/

My answer provides you with a cursory overview of how to achieve what you want to, but depending on your inclination and time availability, you may want to use your discretion before you decide to head onto one path than the other.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As @gagravarr told me to go through run by run then paragraph by paragraph. That's what I wrote in the above code. Before the run by run, code was different. You can check the earlier code also. The above-attached images are the output of earlier code

Comment: When you get an exception, you’re saying, “ System.out.println("We had an error while reading the Word Doc");”     Are you confident that you’re getting an error reading the word file? If yes, got already know the error. If not, what does the exception say? Print e.getMessage() and e.printStackTrace() to know which exception condition is getting caught.